# Wether to use passport library or not?

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport-facebook

Am trying to get Facebook and google login functionality integrated in my node.js app.
I have heard of passport library but has never used it. Can anybody help me,whether to use this library or write the code without it?

link for passport lib:- http://passportjs.org/docs/facebook

if suggesting passport library,kindly share its pros and cons.
TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is basically already done for you with Passport. I would say that and the fact that it has a huge community behind it is it's biggest advantages. If you need an example how to do it (and how easy it is) I recommend from [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) on scotch.io

Comment: am referring to this article only,i have gone through this already.

Comment: Speaking out of experience, the ease of which this lib can be implemented is a major pro. This is because it is such a widely adopted and supported lib. Just look at it's stats on github... This also means that any potential future bug with the lib will be dealt with very quickly as too many people are invested in it. This doesn't mean it is too big to fail, but it sure will make your life much easier when you implement it or need to support it in the future.